# Como pasar datos de un Jtable a otro jtable?

Tags: java

estoy buscando la solucion a este problema ,encontre varias y no puedo dar,
almacenos los datos de la jtable en sqlworkbeanch y se quedan insertadas en una tabla, con un boton guardar,eliminar, etc todo normal hasta ahì, ahora quiero preguntarles como paso esos datos a otra jtable en otra clase... les dejo mi codigo desde ya gracias,solo quiero saber que implemento en el jframe2..

package tablas;

public class VentanaClientes extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();

public VentanaClientes() {

    initComponents();

    try {
        jtProductos.setModel(modelo);
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Conexion conn = new Conexion();
        java.sql.Connection con = conn.getConexion();

        String sql = "SELECT codigo, nombre, precio, cantidad FROM productos";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        ResultSetMetaData rsMd = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
        int cantidadColumnas = rsMd.getColumnCount();

        modelo.addColumn("Código");
        modelo.addColumn("Producto");
        modelo.addColumn("Precio");
        modelo.addColumn("Cantidad");

        int[] anchos = {50, 200, 50, 50};
        for (int i = 0; i < jtProductos.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            jtProductos.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(anchos[i]);
        }

        while (rs.next()) {
            Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas];
            for (int i = 0; i < cantidadColumnas; i++) {
                filas[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
            }
            modelo.addRow(filas);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.toString());
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

Y los demàs botones, desde ya gracias

Answer (score 0):

Una forma seria sobrecargar la firma del constructor de la segunda vista a donde quieres enviar la información, donde la data seria un DefaultTableModel.
ejm:

```
public Vista2(DefaultTableModel dtm){
    initComponents(); // inicializacion de netbeans
    tabla2.setModel(dtm);
}
```

En la primera vista, extraerias el Model de la primera tabla que sera enviada a la segunda. Puedes usar un boton y agregar un listener para ejecutar la accion.
Ejm:

```
private void enviarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

     DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tabla1.getModel();
     Vista2 v2 = new Vista2(dtm);
     v2.setVisible(true);


}
```

Comment: Vale Andy, pero si quisiera hacerlo sin un boton?, de manera que si se guarda en la primera jtable con el boton " Guardar " , aparesca en la otra clase , en la jtable2 lo mismo que en la tabla1 (que esta en otra clase), desde y gracias andy , te pediria que me envies el codigo asi solamente lo implemento!

Answer (score 0):

Para lo otro que sugieres puedes en el constructor de la primera vista o en cualquier momento de tu interes primero desplegar la otra ventana para que la instancia exista inicialmente. En la segunda vista declarar una variable que te permita trabajar con el modelo de la tabla, pero a traves de setter y getters.

En la clase de la vista 1, declarar una variable que instancie la vista 2 y luego se inicializa

```
public class Vista extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private Vista2 v2;
```

Vista 1: Constructor

```
public Vista() {
    initComponents();
    v2 = new Vista2();
    v2.setVisible(true);

}
```

action del boton guardar:

```
private void guardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    DefaultTableModel dtm = v2.getDtm();
    dtm.addRow(new Object []{"1", "avion", "1540", "3h"});


}
```

Clase de la vista 2

```
public class Vista2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private DefaultTableModel dtm;


public Vista2() {
    initComponents();
    dtm = (DefaultTableModel) tabla2.getModel();

}

public DefaultTableModel getDtm() {
    return dtm;
}

public void setDtm(DefaultTableModel dtm) {
    this.dtm = dtm;
}
```

.........por brevedad

Comment: Andy, mira te dejo como lo estoy agregando y no me tira ningun error, pero tampoco hace nada, nose si estoy insertando mal algo, te aclaro que estoy usando sql workbeanch; te agradeceria si me respondes:

Answer (score 0):

Mi clase Cliente:
public class VentanaClientes extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
private VentanaAdministradores v2;

public VentanaClientes() {



    try {
        initComponents();
     v2 = new VentanaAdministradores();
v2.setVisible(true);

        jtProductos.setModel(modelo);
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Conexion conn = new Conexion();
        java.sql.Connection con = conn.getConexion();

        String sql = "SELECT codigo, nombre, precio, cantidad FROM productos";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        ResultSetMetaData rsMd = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
        int cantidadColumnas = rsMd.getColumnCount();

        modelo.addColumn("Código");
        modelo.addColumn("Producto");
        modelo.addColumn("Precio");
        modelo.addColumn("Cantidad");
```

Mi clase Administrador (Donde quiero que aparesca la tabla):
public class VentanaAdministradores extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
/**
 * Creates new form VentanaAdministradores
 */

private DefaultTableModel dtm;

public VentanaAdministradores() {
```

initComponents();
         dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

}
    public DefaultTableModel getDtm() {
    return dtm;
}
public void setDtm(DefaultTableModel dtm) {
    this.dtm = dtm;
}

Mi boton guardar:

```
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        Conexion objCon = new Conexion();
        Connection conn = objCon.getConexion();

        ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO productos (codigo, nombre, precio, cantidad) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, txtCodigo.getText());
        ps.setString(2, txtNombre.getText());
        ps.setString(3, txtPrecio.getText());
        ps.setString(4, txtCantidad.getText());

        ps.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Producto Guardado");
        Object[] fila = new Object[4];
        fila[0] = txtCodigo.getText();
        fila[1] = txtNombre.getText();
        fila[2] = txtPrecio.getText();
        fila[3] = txtCantidad.getText();
        modelo.addRow(fila);

        DefaultTableModel dtm = v2.getDtm();
dtm.addRow(new Object []{"1", "avion", "1540", "3h"});
        limpiar();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al Guardar Producto");
        System.out.println(ex);



    }


}                                          

private void jtProductosMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        Conexion objCon = new Conexion();
        Connection conn = objCon.getConexion();

        int Fila = jtProductos.getSelectedRow();
        String codigo = jtProductos.getValueAt(Fila, 0).toString();

        ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT codigo, nombre, precio, cantidad FROM productos WHERE codigo=?");
        ps.setString(1, codigo);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            txtCodigo.setText(rs.getString("codigo"));
            txtNombre.setText(rs.getString("nombre"));
            txtPrecio.setText(rs.getString("precio"));
            txtCantidad.setText(rs.getString("cantidad"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Te agredeceria mucho la respuesta andy,ya que estoy implementando lo que me dices y no puedo

Comment: Hagamos algo dame el nombre de la clase JFrame de la ventana 2 y el nombre de la tabla. Ya que lo que intentastes hacer tiene unos detalles.